# Filtering Data on a DevExpress GridView

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms, devexpress

I am an MVC person, and have minimal experience with WebForms, but now I am having to add some functionality to a legacy VB.NET WebForms application.

So the application is using DevExpress Grids, and it displays a really long grid view on the page where one of the columns has the following:

[image: radio actions]

The extra functionality that I am asked to add is a filter where the user can say:

> I only want to see the rows where the on-load radio button selected is Print (or one of the other two actions).

So I went to the bottom of the grid and created the following:

[image: filter drop down]

My thinking was, the user can come to this drop down and selected what he or she wants to filter on for radio button actions.

**DevExpress GridView Code**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Theme="Office2010Blue" KeyFieldName="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" Width="3200px">
    <Columns>
        <!-- Many more columns go here -->
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="" VisibleIndex="29" Name="decision" Width="150px">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkPrint" OnClick="SelectPrintAll">Print All</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkEmail" OnClick="SelectEmailAll">Email All</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkIgnore" OnClick="SelectIgnoreAll">Ignore All</asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upRadDecision" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <dx:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="radDecision" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="StoreDecisionForRow" AutoPostBack="True" Height="15px"
                            OnDataBinding="BindDecisionRadioButton">
                            <Border BorderStyle="None"></Border>
                            <Paddings Padding="0"></Paddings>
                            <Items>
                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Print" Value="Print" />
                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Email" Value="Email" />
                                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Ignore" Value="Ignore" />
                            </Items>
                        </dx:ASPxRadioButtonList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </DataItemTemplate>
            <Settings HeaderFilterMode="CheckedList"></Settings>
        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>

    <!-- Stylres -->
    <Styles>
        <AlternatingRow Enabled="true" />
    </Styles>

    <!-- Settings -->
    <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowFilterBar="Auto" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFooter="True" />
    <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectByRowClick="False" />
    <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="False" />
    <SettingsBehavior ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="true" />
    <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />

    <GroupSummary>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" />
    </GroupSummary>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I have added a click handler to my **filter button**, and the code is like so:

```
Private Sub btnFilterDefaults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilterDefaults.Click
    Dim filterOn As String = ddDefaultsFilterOption.SelectedValue
    'Code Handling the Filtering.
    GridView1.filter
    For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To GridView1.VisibleRowCount - 1
        Dim datarow = GridView1.GetDataRow(rowIndex)
        Dim radDecision As ASPxRadioButtonList = CType(GridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(rowIndex, Nothing, "radDecision"), ASPxRadioButtonList)
        Dim decision As String = ""

        If radDecision.Value Is Nothing then Continue For

        decision = radDecision.Value.ToString()

        If decision.Contains(filterOn) Then
            datarow.?? <<<<< no option to hide row here!!! :/
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I was hoping that when I got hold of the data row, I'd be able to hide it, but there is no such option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use [HeaderFilterMode](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/Filtering/HeaderFilter.aspx) for your GridView? This function started from 12 DevExpress version, as I remember. Look at the example below, how you can enable it.

```
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="" VisibleIndex="29" Name="decision" Width="150px">
       ...
       <Settings HeaderFilterMode="CheckedList" />
   </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

If you have older version or you need completely another functionality, you can create your own custom template for filter column. Look at the example on c# below

```
public class FilterLookupTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private const string FormatFilterValue = "FilterLookupTemplateValue_{0}";

    public string ClientIdLookup { get; private set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string DataSourceID { get; set; }
    public ASPxGridView GridView { get; set; }

    #region ITemplate Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialization template
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        (GridView != null).Ensure<ArgumentException>("There didn't passed reference to grid view!");
        if (!GridView.IsClientSideAPIEnabled() || String.IsNullOrEmpty(GridView.ClientInstanceName))
        {
            GridView.ClientInstanceName = GridView.ID;
        }

        var column = GridView.Columns[FieldName] as GridViewDataColumn;
        (column != null).Ensure<ArgumentException>("There is error to get column by name!");
        column.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu = DefaultBoolean.False;
        GridView.AutoFilterCellEditorCreate += OnAutoFilterCellEditorCreate;
        GridView.AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize += OnAutoFilterCellEditorInitialize;
        GridView.ProcessColumnAutoFilter += OnProcessColumnAutoFilter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creating filter dropdown control
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
    private void OnAutoFilterCellEditorCreate(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorCreateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals(FieldName))
        {
            var dde = new DropDownEditProperties { EnableClientSideAPI = true, DropDownWindowTemplate = this };
            e.EditorProperties = dde;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializing filter dropdown control
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
    private void OnAutoFilterCellEditorInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals(FieldName))
        {
            var editor = e.Editor as ASPxDropDownEdit;
            (editor != null).Ensure<ArgumentException>("There wasn't passed reference to the drop down editor!");
            editor.ReadOnly = true
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processing column filtering
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
    private void OnProcessColumnAutoFilter(object sender, ASPxGridViewAutoFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var session = GridView.Page.Session;
        if (e.Kind == GridViewAutoFilterEventKind.CreateCriteria)
        {
            session[String.Format(FormatFilterValue, e.Column.FieldName)] = e.Value;
            if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals(FieldName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
            {
                var values = e.Value.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (values.Length > 0)
                {
                    var action = new Func<string, string, FunctionOperator>((name, value) =>
                              new FunctionOperator(FunctionOperatorType.Contains, new OperandProperty(name), new OperandValue(value)));
                    if (values.Length > 1)
                    {
                        var group = new GroupOperator(GroupOperatorType.Or);
                        group.Operands.AddRange(values.Select(v => action(e.Column.FieldName, v)).ToArray());
                        e.Criteria = group;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Criteria = action(e.Column.FieldName, values[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (session[String.Format(FormatFilterValue, e.Column.FieldName)] != null)
            {
                e.Value = session[String.Format(FormatFilterValue, e.Column.FieldName)].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rendering loolup template controls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">Container of date range template</param>
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        (GridView != null).Ensure<ArgumentException>("There didn't passed reference to grid view!");
        var table = new Table { Width = new Unit(200, UnitType.Pixel) };
        container.Controls.Add(table);

        var row = new TableRow();
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        var cell = new TableCell();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        var lbl = new ASPxLabel { ID = "lblSelect", Text = MessageResources.FilterLookupTemplate_SelectLabelText };
        cell.Controls.Add(lbl);

        cell = new TableCell();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        var lookup = new ASPxGridLookup
                         {
                             ID = GridView.ID + "lookupValues",
                             EnableClientSideAPI = true,
                             Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage),
                             SelectionMode = GridLookupSelectionMode.Multiple
                         };
        lookup.GridView.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
        lookup.GridView.DataSourceID = DataSourceID;
        lookup.GridView.KeyFieldName = "id";
        lookup.GridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewCommandColumn { ShowSelectCheckbox = true, AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False });
        var nameColumn = new GridViewDataTextColumn { FieldName = "name" };
        nameColumn.Settings.AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False;
        nameColumn.Settings.AllowGroup = DefaultBoolean.False;
        nameColumn.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
        nameColumn.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        lookup.GridView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        lookup.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
        cell.Controls.Add(lookup);
        ClientIdLookup = lookup.ClientID;
        row = new TableRow();
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        cell = new TableCell { ColumnSpan = 2 };
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        var lnk = new ASPxHyperLink { Text = MessageResources.FilterLookupTemplate_ApplyLinkText, NavigateUrl = "#" };
        lnk.ClientSideEvents.Click =
            String.Format("function (s, e) {{ {0}.HideDropDown(); ApplyLookupFilter({0}, {1}, '{2}', {3}); }}",
                          container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.ClientID,
                          GridView.ClientInstanceName,
                          FieldName,
                          ClientIdLookup);
        cell.Controls.Add(lnk);
        container.Controls.Add(table);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and then register it for your grid view. ReportsCustomerDataSource is a LINQ data source control.

```
public partial class YourPage: Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        new FilterLookupTemplate { FieldName = "ReportCustomers", DataSourceID = ReportsCustomerDataSource.ID, GridView = _gridView }.Init();
    }
}
```

On the form it will be look like that

[image]

Comment: My column is not a standard column, like for example **Color** where the rows hold the color value.

Comment: I wrote a lot of none standard columns as well as Color column, just provide your gridview settings in question

Comment: I have updated my question, and added the GridView code like you requested. Please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to add. Thx

Comment: I have DevExpress v12.1, I tried your code (after commenting out the stuff I added), but I do not see anything different! I see no filtering capability. What and where am I suppose to see a change? Thx

Comment: On the filter row, I added the screenshot to the answer

Comment: That is not appearing for me :( You noticed my grid view uses `GridViewDataColumn`? Cause that screenshot of yours does work on columns where the column type is `GridViewDataTextColumn`, but not for when it is of type `GridViewDataColumn`

Comment: Am I adding that filter line of code to the right place? I have updated my Q to show that new addition. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you're trying to apply a visible trait to a datarow.  What you want to do is use GridViewRow instead.  It's the presentation object.  Sorry I don't have an example for you but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a link to msdn for it

Comment: Interesting, but when I access my grid (dev express) there is no `.GetGridViewRow()`